# the composite of normal and separable extensions of fields

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K/F$ be a normal extension of fields and $L/F$ be a separable extension of fields, show that $[KL:L]=[K:K\cap L]$.

Comment: What have you tried? Ordinarily, people expect to see a question fully developed, with an explanation of what you know, what you’ve tried, and where you got stuck. If this is a homework problem from a course, you’d better say that, too.

Comment: @Lubin I just saw this problem in one book